# Stop specific Twig template from rendering anything

Tags: templating

If i want specific template to stop from rendering anything, I use `if`:

```
{% if something %}
HTML markup...
{% endif %}
```

This however requires wrapping whole Template in `if` which is not ideal for readbility.

Is there maybe some kind of Twig function which when used stops rendering template in which it is used? Like this:

```
{% if something %}
    {% do stopRendering() %}
{% endif %}

HTML markup (will show up if we didnt stopped rendering)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you exactly need to happen, the `{% exit %}` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#exit)) tag my be an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

If this related to an entire twig template, you could include it inside an if statement:

```
{% if not devMode %}{% include '_includes/google-analytics.twig' -%}{%  endif %}
```

If you need to exit a twig template early (based on some value), Oli's answer is what you might want to look at.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if not currentUser %}{# or whatever #}
    {% exit 401 %}{# Or whatever HTTP status appropriate template it should be #}
{% endif %}

... the rest of your template ...
```